# Are two principal ideals are equal if their generator has the same root in some extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I recently came across the following claim in a paper concerning polyonomials in $\mathcal{R}_p = \mathbb{Z}_p[X]/\langle X^d + 1\rangle$ (where $\mathbb{Z}_p = \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}p$) and their automorphism $\sigma_i: X \mapsto X^i$.

$$\sigma_i \langle X - \alpha \rangle = \langle X^i - \alpha \rangle = \langle X - \alpha^{i^{-1}} \rangle$$

where the latter (according to the authors) follows as the generators have the same roots in (in some extension of the base field $\mathbb{Z}_p$), where $X - \alpha$ is irreducible modulo $p$ for prime $p$.

I can see that they would have *a* same root in an appropriate extension, but I don't understand how that leads to the claim that they are equal in the base field itself.

It's been a while since I took algebra but what I remember is that two principal ideals of a ring $\langle a \rangle$ and $\langle b \rangle$ are equal if there is a unit $u$ in the ring such that $a = bu$. Is it simple enough to find such a unit here? How do we get the claim (ie., generators have same roots therefore principal ideals are equal) from this?

Comment: It is hard to say for sure. Which ring are we working over? If $K$ is an extension field containing $\alpha^{1/i}$, and we are looking at ideals in the polynomial ring $K[X]$, then the claim is obviously false. After all, the principal ideal on the left has no non-zero polynomials of degrees $<i$ whereas the principal ideal on the right obviously contains a linear polynomial. I'm afraid you have left out some essential context, but possibly the writer messed it up.

Comment: Anyway, the argument about the zeros is strange. With the (in my opinion only) sensical interpretation the polynomial $X-\alpha^{1/i}$ has a single zero, but the other generator may have as many as $i$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Indeed I did leave out some context, that's on me. The paper is [this one](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/517.pdf). The claim is made in the short sub-section 2.2. It is not a math paper, so there does seem to be some hand-waving, or perhaps I have misinterpreted something.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the description of the ring. As promised last night I added a toy example. Because the powers of $X$ are calculated modulo $X^d+1$, the scene is radically different from my first comment. Most notably because $X^d=-1$ in the ring $\mathcal{R}_p$. I will probably add a more convincing example later, because the chosen one is very trivial. I posted the toy example mostly to A) make sure that we are on the same page about what the question is, and B) it is too long to fit into a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The precise description of the ring $\mathcal{R}_p$ added to the question explains what is going on. I lead off with a very simple toy example to get the ball rolling.

I consider the case of $p=13$, $d=16$ (the parameter $d$ is always a power of two).
As further prescribed in section 2.2. of [the linked article](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/517.pdf) we can then choose $\ell=2$ as
$$
p-1=12\equiv 2\ell\pmod{4\ell},
$$
or, equivalently, $4=2^2=2\ell$ is the highest power of two that divides $p-1$.

Modulo $p=13$ we have
$$(\pm 5)^2=25\equiv-1\pmod{13},$$
so the fourth roots of unity modulo $p$ are $\zeta=5$ and $\zeta^3=-\zeta=8$. Consequently the polynomial $X^{16}+1$ factors as
$$
X^{16}+1=(X^8-5)(X^8-8)\pmod{13},
$$
which you can also easily verify by hand.

As a part of the toy example let's consider the (ring) automorphism $\sigma_3$ of $\mathcal{R}_{13}$ defined by $X\mapsto X^3$. If I understood correcly, the question is then about the equality of the principal ideals (line 12 of section 2.2. in the source)
$$\sigma_3(\langle X^8-5\rangle)=\langle X^{24}-5\rangle$$
and
$$\langle X^8-5^{1/3}\rangle.$$
Here $8^3=5$ (compare this with the usual calculation with fourth roots of unity: $i^3=-i$), so we can use $5^{1/3}=8$ ($\dagger$). Furthermore, because the arithmetic of polynomials of $X$ is done modulo $X^d+1=X^{16}+1$, we have $X^{16}=-1$ in the quotient ring $\mathcal{R}_{13}$. Therefore
$$
X^{24}-5=X^{16}\cdot X^8-5=-X^8-5=-(X^8-8).
$$
In other words, the two generators $X^8-8$ and $X^{24}-5$ are gotten from each other by multiplication with $-1$.

---

Adding another example with more maximal ideals. Need a higher power of two dividing $p-1$, so let's use $p=41$ and $d=32$, when
$$
p-1\equiv 2\cdot4\pmod{4\cdot4}.
$$
This time $\ell=4$, so we get four maximal ideals generated by the factors
$$x^{32}+1=(x^8-3)(x^8-14)(x^8+3)(x^8+14).$$
Here $3^4=81\equiv-1\pmod{41}$ and $3^8\equiv1\pmod{41}$. Hence $3$ is of order eight, and so are $3^3=27\equiv-14$ and their negatives.

Let's again study the effect of $\sigma_3$ on the maximal ideals (an automorphism will always map a maximal ideal to another, and the question is just which). Because $3\cdot3\equiv1\pmod 8$ we have $\zeta^9\equiv\zeta$ for every primitive eighth root $\zeta\in\Bbb{Z}_{41}$. This means that we can use
$$\zeta^{1/3}=\zeta^3=\frac{\zeta^4}{\zeta}=-\frac1{\zeta}.$$
This time $X^{32}=-1$, and therefore $X^{24}=X^{-8}\cdot X^{32}=-X^{-8}$. Consequently
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sigma_3(X^8-\zeta)&=X^{24}-\zeta\\
&=-X^{-8}-\zeta\\
&=-\zeta X^{-8}(\frac1\zeta+X^8).
\end{aligned}
$$
As $-\zeta X^{-8}$ is a unit of the ring $\mathcal{R}_{41}$, this means
that
$$
\langle\sigma_3(X^8-\zeta)\rangle=\langle X^8-(-1/\zeta)\rangle
=\langle X^8-\zeta^{1/3}\rangle 
$$
exactly as the authors claimed!

---

I'm aware that I haven't yet answered the title question about zeros of polynomials in an extension field. Nevertheless, I hope that that the examples lift some of the fog. A particular fact that may become as a surprise to the unwary is that $X$ and its powers are units in this ring.

---

($\dagger$) The element $5$ has no less than three cube roots in $\Bbb{Z}_{13}$. I use $8$ because it is the only one that is another fourth root of unity (the other two both have order twelve). I think that is the intention of the authors also.

Comment: This is great! In the first example, if we were to consider the automorphism $\sigma_2$ instead, would we then adjoin $\sqrt{5}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ and do the rest of the work in this extension? That is, $(X^{16} - 5) = (X^8 + \sqrt{5}) (X^8 - \sqrt{5})$ and (if I did my work correctly) the former is a unit in the extension with inverse $(-11X^8 - 2\sqrt{5})$.

Comment: It would be very helpful to readers if you put the non-answer disclaimer at the *start* of the answer.

Comment: @aayad I don't think we can ever have $\sigma_2$, because $X^2$ is no longer a root of $-1$ of order $d$. In section 2.2 the authors only use automorphisms $\sigma_i$ with $i\in\Bbb{Z}_{2d}^*$. In other words, $i$ is always odd.

Comment: On the other hand, the polynomial $X^D+1$ does factor further, if we move from the field $\Bbb{Z}_p$ to an extension field  $K$ of degree that is a power of two. Replacing the ring $\mathcal{R}_p$ with $\mathcal{R}\otimes K\simeq K[X]/\langle X^d+1\rangle$. The maximal ideals then become larger in comparison as they are factors of the maximal ideals of the subring.

Comment: I don't quite follow -- why is $X^2$ is no longer a root of $-1$?

Comment: It is, but $(X^2)^{d/2}=-1$ and as a root of unity it has order $d$ (as opposed to $2d$, which is the order of $X$). An automorphism needs to preserve the order of a root of unity.

Comment: Phrased differently, we have $X^d=-1$. If $\sigma$ is an automorphism with the property $\sigma(X)=X^2$, then it follows that
$$\sigma(X^d)=\sigma(X)^d=(X^2)^d=(X^d)^2=(-1)^2=1.$$
This contradicts the fact that we must have $\sigma(-1)=-1$.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand. Thank you for clarifying. Would you also have some intuition for the more general answer to this question? I'm not sure where to even start.