# Confusion over the use of the term "module" in mathematics and post-quantum cryptography.

Tags: modules, terminology, cryptography, vector-lattices

In post-quantum cryptography, there's a suite of algorithms based on "modular lattice". These schemes are defined in terms of vectors and matrices whose elements are polynomials of a fixed degree (e.g. 256 for ML-KEM/[Kyber](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/634) as well as ML-DSA/[Dilithium](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/633)).

Also, there's the "[module](https://handwiki.org/wiki/Module%20(mathematics))" mathematical object, which is a generalization of vector space as I read it.

Then there's a statement in NIST [draft](https://csrc.nist.gov/pubs/fips/204/ipd) for ML-DSA:

> When the module $\mathbb{Z}^n_q$ in LWE and SIS is replaced by a module over a ring larger than $\mathbb{Z}_q$ (such as $R_q$), the resulting problems are called MLWE (Module Learning With Errors [14]) and MSIS (Module Short Integer Solution). The security of ML-DSA is based on the MLWE problem over Rq and a nonstandard variant of MSIS called SelfTargetMSIS [15].

which confuses me to the point I submitted a (possibly stupid) [comment](https://csrc.nist.gov/files/pubs/fips/204/ipd/docs/fips-204-initial-public-comments-2023.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A23%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C70%2C720%2C0%5D).

This is mostly a terminology question, so **Q**: what do these various "modules" mean outside of and relation to lattice-based post-quantum cryptography

---

As far as I can tell, according to [the team behind Kyber and Dilithium](https://pq-crystals.org/), their "module lattice" is a blend between the lattice used in LWE and the lattice used in Ring-LWE. They invented the term and avoided already-existing "modular lattice" which I've mistakenly used towards the beginning of this question.

However, the other modules have established meanings in mathematics. I'm just not sure if this is the correct interpretation.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Please don't mistake me as a newbie. I know what LWE and SIS are, and how their ring and modular variants differs, and I've exercised implementing the 2 algorithms in C. I just realized my understanding of "module" may be limited, so I seek to know its other meanings. The URL links in my question points to 1.) HandWiki - a more accessible copy of Wikipedia in my locastion, 2.) IACR - the well known international academic institute on crypto, and 3.) NIST - an American government organ, so you can rest assured that their contents are safe.

Comment: When you ask "what do these modules mean", what do *you* mean? Are you asking about these modules independently of your context, or are you asking for a clarification in the context you've provided? I've gone a little bit through the linked documentation and your linked comment - to me as a **non-expert** $\mathbb Z_q^n$ seems like a viable domain for the SIS problem. Now, $\mathbb Z_q^n$ is a ring but it's also a module over $\mathbb Z_q$, so just on face value (again, I'm not an expert) nothing looks out of place in the sentence "When the module $\mathbb Z_q^n$ ..."

Comment: @RandyMarsh I'm asking about the meaning of module outside of the context of lattice-based PQC, as well as its relation to module-lattice-based PQC. I'll clarify question.

Comment: On the other hand, in your suggested correction "When the ring Zq (such as Rq) in LWE ..." the usage of "such as" does not make sense to me. $R_q$ is not a ring 'such as' $\mathbb Z_q$. $R_q$ has it's own definition $R_q = \mathbb Z_q[X]/(X^{256} + 1)$, it's not a "placeholder" symbol which can be filled in with $\mathbb Z_q$.

Comment: I also do not understand what you're referring to by "various modules."  As you said, the most common meaning of "module" is the "generalization of a vector space" definition. It seems likely to me that [this meaning is the relevant one for your paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(module)). Nobody but you has mentioned [modular lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice) which I think is not (directly) relevant.

Comment: This should be migrated to crypto.se.  Danny is a known entity and I'm sure someone will know the answer.

Comment: Coincidentally, the same ring made an appearance in [another question from yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4881277/11619). We can answer this here, once the fog has cleared up somewhat. As rschwieb said the first version of the title was a bit misleading. The reason for that is that words *modular* and *lattice* are overloaded in math. A modular lattice commonly refers to an order-theoretic object (like what you get when you consider bitmasks and only concern yourself with bitwise logical operations: AND, OR, etc.).

Comment: (cont'd) A lattice can also (as is the case in crypto) refer to a discrete mesh of points in a vector space (probably related to realm of MLWE and friends). And module vs. modular is also a bit fuzzy in the sense *modular arithmetic* is closer (in context) to *modules*.

Comment: Anyway, I'm not conversant with MLWE at all (even though my 2nd PhD student has published on the theme). May be the lattice here is still $\Bbb{Z}_q^n$, but extra structure of an $\mathcal{R}_q$-module is imposed on it, severely constraining the collection of submodules, but also giving more tools to play with.